# Determinant of rectangular block matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have two square matrices $X = \begin{bmatrix}
 A&0 \\ 
 C&D 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{bmatrix}
 D&C \\ 
 0&A 
\end{bmatrix}$ where $A,D,C$ are rectangular matrices.
Could you please tell me how can I prove $det(X)=det(Y)$?

P/S: At first, I thought that I could have applied Schur complements. Unfortunately, these matrices $A,D, C$ are rectangular.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184825/upper-triangular-block-matrix-determinant-by-induction

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is *almost* true. In particular, $Y$ is obtained by permuting the rows and the columns of $X$, i.e., $Y = P X Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are permutation matrices. Thus, in general
$$
\det(Y) = \det(P)\det(X)\det(Q) = \pm \det(X).
$$
For example, if we consider
$$
X = \left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
then we have
$$
Y = \left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
In this case, $\det(X)=1$, but $\det(Y) = -1$