# Questions concerning $ \det ({}^A_{C\,}{}^B_D) = \det ({}^D_{B\,}{}^C_A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A, B, C, D $ be $n \times n $ matrices. Using Schur complements I have found that 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ C & I \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} I & A^{-1}B \\ 0 & D-CA^{-1}B \end{pmatrix}  $$
and
$$ \begin{pmatrix} D & C \\ B & A \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} I & CA^{-1} \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} D-CA^{-1}B & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ A^{-1}B & I \end{pmatrix},  $$
 from which the determinant equality follows, as long as $ A^{-1} $ exists. However, how do I tackle this when $A$ is singular? Here, I could just switch decompositions, but then I will get the same problem when $D$ is singular. Maybe one could derive two more decompositions using Schur complements, involving $B^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$, respectively, and then one could say that the equality holds if at least one of the submatrices is nonsingular? Then, if all four submatrices are singular, the determinant must be zero -- from which equality follows trivially.

Also, does the equality hold when $A, B, C, D$ are not necessarily square but of matching sizes? Here, it doesn't seem like the decompositions will be valid, as $A$ or $D$ aren't necessarily square matrices (although then $B$ and $C$ must be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't it be much easier to consider row/column swaps? By performing $n$ row swaps, you transform 
$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\C & D \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} C&D\\A&B\end{pmatrix},$$
then $n$ column swaps transforms 
$$\begin{pmatrix} C&D\\A&B\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} D&C\\B&A \end{pmatrix}.$$
Each row/column swap multiplies the determinant by $-1$, so this whole process multiplies the determinant by $(-1)^{2n} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is also applicable when the constituent matrices are not necessarily squares. Then, if $A$ is $n \times m$, $B$ is $n \times n$, $C$ is $m \times m$ and $D$ is $m \times n$, we can perform $mn$ row swaps to get  $$ \begin{pmatrix} C & D \\ A & B \end{pmatrix}, $$ and then $mn$ columns swaps will give us the desired result. Since $ (-1)^{2mn} = 1 $, the determinant will be left invariant.

Comment: Now I realize that the reasoning in my previous comment was incorrect. Let $$ \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} $$ be $ n \times n $. In the most general case, $ A $ is $ m_1 \times  m_2 $, while the other submatrices are constrained by this. Then, after swapping rows and columns, we will have a multiplied the orginal determinant by $ (-1)^{m_2 (n-m_2) + m_1 (n-m_1)} $, which is not equal to one for all situations that may be imagined. A simple counterexample resides here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477109/determinant-of-rectangular-block-matrix

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to take advantage of the continuity of the determinant.  In particular, if $A$ is singular, we have
$$
\det \pmatrix{A &B\\C&D} = \lim_{t \to 0} \det\pmatrix{A + tI & B\\C&D}
= \lim_{t \to 0} \det \pmatrix{D&C\\B&A + tI} = 
\det \pmatrix{D&C\\B&A}
$$
Alternatively, you could have noted that
$$
\pmatrix{D&C\\B&A} = \pmatrix{0&I\\I&0} \pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} \pmatrix{0&I\\I&0}
$$
from there, we would only need to show that
$$
\det \pmatrix{0&I_n\\I_n&0} = (-1)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following proposition:

Let $ A=\begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ where $A\in M_{m_1+m_2,n_1,n+2}$. Then we have

(a) If $A_{11}$ is invertible, then $\det A = \det (A_{11}) \det(A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12})$.

(b) If $A_{22}$ is invertible, then $\det A = \det (A_{22}) \det(A_{11}-A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21})$.

This answers your question in case if A or D in your notation is not invertible, for when $A$ is invertible, use (a) and if $A$ is not but $D$ is then use (b). (The proof of the proposition is similar to what you have shown above). Also the matrices $A_{i,j}$ need not necessarily be square, but they should be of matching sizes.

Furthermore, using this proposition, it is a trivial observation that if at least one of $A$ and $D$ is non-singular then
$ \det \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} D & C \\ B & A \end{pmatrix} $

Finally, we require at least one of the two matrices on the principal diagonal , that is $A$ or $D$ to be non-singular.