# Determinant of a block matrix $2n$ by $2n$

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

> Consider the block $2n \times 2n$ matrix
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ 0&D \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> where $A,B,D$ are $n \times n$ blocks. Show that
>
> $$\det\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ 0&D \end{bmatrix}=\det(A)\det(D)$$

So, I'm thinking maybe induction on the size of the matrices $A,B,D$ is the best way to approach this problem.

For $n=1, A=[a], B=[b], D=[d]$
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&d
\end{bmatrix}=ad-b\cdot 0=\det(A)\det(D)$$
Now let us suppose that the claim is true for the $n$ by $n$ matrices $A,B,D$.

We have to prove that this is true for the matrices $A,B,D$ of size $n+1$ by $n+1$.

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n+1\text{x}n+1}&B_{n+1\text{x}n+)}\\
0&D_{n+1\text{x}n+1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

I feel like I just ran into a circular argument. How can this proof be done with induction, if at all?

Comment: This could be done using the definition of determinant that involves signs and patterns, noting that any pattern which uses an element of $B$ must also use an element of $0$ and will contribute nothing to the overall sum.  Further, any pattern of $A$ can be combined with any pattern of $D$ to get a pattern from the larger matrix.  After some tricky reorganizing of terms and factoring, you arrive at the intended result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determinant of a block lower triangular matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix)

Comment: Split into two cases, if $A$ is singular, then the matrix is singular hence the result is true. If $A$ is invertible, then you can multiply by $\operatorname{diag} (A^{-1}, I)$ (whose $\det$ is ${1 \over \det A}$) to get the result.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That other question isn't about a proof by induction. Arturo mentions induction in a comment, but neither the question nor the answers do.

Comment: There is another question which asks for proof by induction: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184825/upper-triangular-block-matrix-determinant-by-induction

Comment: I think that you should be able to prove $\det\begin{pmatrix}I&U\\0&V\end{pmatrix}=\det(V)$ and $\det\begin{pmatrix}X&Y\\0&I\end{pmatrix}=\det(X)$ by induction (on the size of the block with the identity matrix). Then you could try to get the given matrix as a product of matrices of these types.

Comment: But if you want to try this by induction for the matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&D\end{pmatrix}$, then induction on the size of $A$ seems reasonable. Inductive step could be Laplace expansion w.r.t. the first column. (However, you will have to prove a stronger claim - sizes of $A$ and $D$ can be different.)